# Load JSON data from CloudTrail into DynamoDB using Boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, amazon-cloudtrail

I am working on a Boto3 script that can load the attributes from Cloudtrail into Dynamodb. The format of my cloudtrail logs is JSON. I am fairly new to DynamoDB and I am not sure where I am making a mistake. I'm trying to store "S3BucketName" as well as the name of the bucket which is "goodbucket3". Name for the cloudtrail is "GoodTrail".This is what I have come up with so far. I am getting this error "ResourceNotFoundException: An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the PutItem operation: Requested resource not found"

```
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

table =dynamodb.create_table(
    TableName='GoodTable',
    AttributeDefinitions=[
    {
      "AttributeName": "S3BucketName",
      "AttributeType": "S"
    }
    ],
      KeySchema=[
    {
      "AttributeName": "S3BucketName",
      "KeyType": "HASH"
    }
  ],
  ProvisionedThroughput={
    "ReadCapacityUnits": 1,
    "WriteCapacityUnits": 1
  }
)

table = dynamodb.Table('GoodTable')
response = table.put_item(
    Item= {
        'S3BucketName': 'some-bucket-name', 
        'content': f'{path}',
    }
)
```

Comment: What is the issue? Any error messages?

Comment: ResourceNotFoundException: An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the PutItem operation: Requested resource not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `table` is just a dictionary. It is not dynamodb's [table](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#table) object.

To rectify the issue:

```
import boto3

dynamodb_res = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

table = dynamodb_res.Table('GoodTable')

response = table.put_item(
    Item= {
        'S3BucketName': 'some-bucket-name', 
        'content': f'{path}',
    }
)

print(response)
```

Based on your definition, you don't have any `id`. Your primary key in your table is `S3BucketName`, not `id`.

Comment: I have made changes according to your suggestion, but still seem to be having the same issue with the error "ResourceNotFoundException: An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the PutItem operation: Requested resource not found".I have made the changes in the question as well. TIA.

Comment: @PranaySinghParihar Your code is incomplete, and can't produce such an error. You would get syntax error first due to undefined `path`. I suggest provide fully reproducible code which correctly reflects your actual codebase.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out, it was happening because the table takes time to be created, and after that was completed, I would be able to add characters, so I just added time.sleep. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @PranaySinghParihar Glad it worked out and no problem:-)